# Old files remain in new docker container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a basic Hyperledger Fabric network where the nodes uses docker containers.

Inside each node I have done some file creation and editing. However, I now want to restart the network with clean containers.

I have tried to shut down all containers, images and networks, then run the docker prune command. 
I have also tried to delete all volumes.

However, once I re-create the Fabric network, when bashing into a container the old files that I custom created are still there. I never created those files on host machine, only inside that container. But I do not understand how it is possible that those files still exists. I even tried to delete the images.

System is Ubuntu 18.4

Can anybody spot the potential fix to this?

Comment: i met this problem once, i was using --no-cache, --force-recreate, --force rm, build options in  my docker-compose file ... until i noticed that some of my files wasn't set with the right permissions. My IDE Intellij, let me edit files but don't warn me that my changes weren't saved... i had lost hours and hours trying to figure whats the problem.. and finally... permissions problems..

Comment: If you are using docker-compose, use `docker-compose down -v`. It will remove any externally attached volumes also, so that you can create new network.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the volumes of the containers after stopping and removing the containers by below commands,

docker kill $(docker ps -aq)

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

Then remove the volumes of the containers by below command.

docker system prune --volumes -f

This removes all the unused networks and volumes .

Hope this helps.